# When 'firebase -serve' is OK, though 'firebase -deploy' is not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

It works in locally ( firebase - serve) but, when it upload on cloud, it is not work (firebase -deploy)
 I have no idea why it isn't work.

```js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\WIZnet\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-26T07_40_15_700Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2

Having trouble? Try firebase deploy --help
```

Anyone plz?

Comment: The error message says "There is likely additional logging output above."  Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try running tslint and fix your code.
`firebase serve` doesnt run tslint, though `firebase deploy` has predeploy hook to run tslint.

thats why you have that issue only when deploying.

---

If you read `firebase.json` carefully, you will find this.

```
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
```